# Load images based on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML code which displays an image:

```
<div>
     <img id="wm01" alt="PP" title="PP" u="image" src="theImages/wm01.jpg" />
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is display a different image depending on the screen size. So first I hide the image with CSS:

```
#wm01 {
    display: none;
}
```

And then in my BODY, I add the following code:

```
var w = window,
d = document,
e = d.documentElement,
g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
if (x<568) {
    //alert(x);
    document.getElementById("wm01").src="theImages/wm01_app.jpg";
    document.getElementById("wm01").style.display = "block";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("wm01").src="theImages/wm01.jpg";
    document.getElementById("wm01").style.display = "block";
}
```

The image is not showing in any size screen. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why not just use media queries?

Comment: I can't set the source of an image using css... right?

Comment: Why not use a background image instead?

Comment: It is part of a slider script which is why I won't be able to use background image :/

Comment: yeah i was wondering the same thing @ Derek S

Answer (score 28):

No one has suggested using a [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) element yet.

`<picture>` has the nice feature that you can specify different images for different window sizes.

For example:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="some-bigger.png" media="(min-width: 500px)">
    <img src="some.png" alt="Some picture">
</picture>
```

For you it would be:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="theImages/wm01_app.jpg" media="(min-width: 568px)">
    <img src="theImages/wm01.jpg" alt="PP">
</picture>
```

Which says, use `theImages/wm01_app.jpg` whenever the device width is, at minimum, `568px`.  Otherwise use the default `<img>` source.

Comment: picture is not available on all browsers. I used this polyfill which worked out very nicely for me- https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

Answer (score 9):

Why not use `srcset` and `sizes` attributes of the `<img>`

```
<img srcset="tiger-320w.jpg 320w,
             tiger-480w.jpg 480w,
             tiger-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (max-width: 480px) 440px,
            800px"
     src="tiger-800w.jpg" alt="Bengal tiger">
```

For more reference go though [Responsive_images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)

It supported by [all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=srcset)

Comment: Obviously IE doesn't support this.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro yeah that's why I put `caniuse` link on description.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest CSS media query first and then JavaScript if you need to support a browser that doesn't support media query. This example uses 850px as a maximum width before the image is changed.

CSS:

```
/* media query device layout transformation for 850px width trigger */
#wm01 { 
     background:url(images/large_image.png);
     width:100px;
     height:50px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:850px) {
     #wm01 {
         background:url(images/smaller_image.png);
     }
}
```

JS/JQuery:

```
var width = $(window).width();
if (width >= 850) {
    $('#wm01').addClass('largeImageClass');
} else {
    $('#wm01').addClass('smallImageClass');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wm01" alt="PP" title="PP" u="image" /><!--comment for legacy browser --></div>
<img id="wm01" alt="PP" title="PP" u="image" />
```

Comment: It is changing the background but I am using an image

Comment: you could do instead <div id="wm01"></div> instead of the image and the image will come from your CSS definition for #wm01

Comment: I will upvote as this could be an option but the images are part of a slider which requires an image tag to be used.

Comment: I added an example of using a DIV or an image. Both should work.

Comment: Glad I can help. In most cases you can eliminate the image source and define it in CSS instead. You need to specify the width and height in the CSS for the image to appear with correct dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting, ongoing, problem. There is no one right way but here are some options:

- http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/09/19/responsive-images-for-html5/
- http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/

Comment: Links are not answers.

Answer (score 4):

Other have suggested alternatives methods to solve the problem of multiple images, but with your proposed solution, the problem is you're trying to give an image the src before the DOM is ready. Make sure everything is loaded with window.onload, and it'll work. Change your code to:

```
var w = window,
d = document,
e = d.documentElement,
g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

// The onload:
window.onload = function(){
    if (x<568) {
        document.getElementById("wm01").src="theImages/wm01_app.jpg";
        document.getElementById("wm01").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("wm01").src="theImages/wm01.jpg";
        document.getElementById("wm01").style.display = "block";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a media query to shrink the image and show a background image.

*Note: this method requires you know the size/proportions of the replacement image.*

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FmLgS/1/)**

```
<img id="wm01" alt="PP" title="PP" u="image" src="theImages/wm01.jpg" />

@media screen and (max-width:568px) {
  #wm01 {
    background: url("theImages/wm01_app.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    padding-bottom: 300px; /* replace with height of wm01_app.jpg */
    padding-right: 300px; /* replace with width of wm01_app.jpg */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do same thing in my website using this code, and works perfect for me.

**HTML**

```
<figure class="picture"></figure>
```

**JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    if(w <= 650){
      $(".picture").html("<img src='images-min.jpg'/>")
    }
    else if(w>650 && w<=1300){
      $(".picyure").html("<img src='images-med.jpg'/>")
    }
    else{
      $(".picture").html("<img src='images-big.jpg'/>")
    }
});
```

in this case I use three diferent size of images.