# Adapting images to different screen widths for faster loading time

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a website with slide show, and I'd like those slides to be high quality for somebody who views website on a large screen. But the problem is if I load images with 4096*1800px into my image folder it looks good on any device, but when I'm trying to load website on my phone I don't really need that high of an image quality, I'd rather load something like 400*180px, that image would be 10 times less in size.

So my plan is to have html load different images dependently on screen resolution.
I thought about writing a script that would make a change in a regular html like this:
Change this:

```
<img src="img/slide1.jpg">
```

To this:

```
<img src="img/1200px/slide1.jpg">
```

Or this:

```
<img src="img/600px/slide1.jpg">
```

and so on.

Is this the best way to do it, or are there better ways?
Thanks a lot

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414817/load-images-based-on-screen-size

Comment: Looks good to me. I do it slightly differently though. I keep the images in same folder and name them slide.jpg slide1600x1200.jpg slide300x300.jpg etc but that's just my preference.

Comment: Eventually (in some years...) we can use the [`srcset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset) attribute of the `<img />` tag

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to find the best responsive image solution. I personally prefer the [HISRC](https://github.com/teleject/hisrc) with a jQuery and Html approach using a html tag as shown below,

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100" data-1x="http://placekitten.com/400/200" data-2x="http://placekitten.com/800/400" class="hisrc" />
```

and a javaScript as shown below,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hisrc").hisrc();
});
```

but there are many other type of solutions which you might be more prefered as shown [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/)