# In Django, how can I load images based on screen size?

Tags: python, django

Apologies for not having any specific broken code here. I already know that what I would try won't work from a different question here, and I have a vague idea of something that might work but is likely not the best way to do it.

I'm building a website for a photographer, so it's important that I'm loading the best looking photos that the user is capable of seeing. The starting file size for the images is a few MB, but the model uses Pillow to save down-scaled copies. There are times when I want a full-screen image at high resolution, but I want to serve a smaller image if the user is on mobile, for example.

What I would have done was load the images from CSS background-image with media queries, but I understand that I can't use template tags in CSS.

My next guess would be to build two separate versions of each template and have the views render a different template based on the user-agent of the request, but that strikes me as probably not a great solution to put that much trust in the request headers, and the functionality could break as easily as a new browser release. There's a better way, right?

**Why not CSS?** - In this case, the images are dynamic content. The photographer doesn't know web development and I'm not going to update the site for him every time he adds or removes images or blog posts, etc, so the site is a lite CMS. He can freely add or remove images from galleries, etc. The django view/template then find and serve the images from the query set. Instead of referring to specific images and their specific smaller versions, I'm asking the server to serve whatever images currently belong to a specific queryset in the database, and serve either the smaller or larger versions of the images, and to do so with the explicit goal of not having the user download resolution that they can't see.

Comment: Since you already have the pics in various sizes on the server, it looks like the job would be best done using HTML, CSS or Javascript on the client rather than on the server. You could rewrite the question to be less Django-specific and add other tags for better chances at an anwser.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414817/load-images-based-on-screen-size and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: Ah, I see that an edit was needed for more info. Client side won't work because the images are dynamic content.

Comment: @KyleAlm I still think you can do on client side. When a photographer uploads a photo, he can create an instance of, say, a `Photograph` model than contains several `ImageField`s for the different sizes, generated when saving the model. When a user browses the website, querysets of `Photograph` instances are made. These are available in the template that could expose the URLs for all sizes (for each `Photograph` object). The right image could then be chosen by the client, using CSS/JS/HTML. In summary, the choice of image size does not need to be done at the level of the query to the database.

Comment: @mimo - Hmm... okay, I think I might be following. Could I, say, have the template pass the URLs to a DIVs data attribute where it wouldn't be loaded, and then conditionally grab that with javascript to set the appropriate url to render?

Comment: @KyleAlm Yes, something like that. This way, you would have a responsive website that follows the usual recommendation to serve the same HTML data to all clients but let them decide how to display. And, back to my initial point, your problem is then more generic than a Django problem.